# Как в данном примере отменить действия браузера по умолчанию при использовании стрелок вверх/вниз?

Tags: javascript

```js
let input    = document.querySelector('.input'),
    variants = document.querySelector('.variantsDiv'),
    wordsObject = {
        'a' : ['amy',  'any', 'aky', 'ammy', 'aby', 'aty', 'azy', 'ally', 'aly'],
        'b' : ['boy', 'boom', 'by', 'burn', 'build', 'back', 'background', 'boo'],
        'p' : ['pick', 'pook']
    };


let varMod = (function(){

    /////////////////////////// (1) ///////////////////////////
    function createSpanItems(input, variantsBlock, objOfWords){ 
        let val = input.value.toLowerCase(),
            firstLetter = val.slice(0,1).toLowerCase(),
            curArray,
            variants = [];

        if(objOfWords[firstLetter]){
            curArray = objOfWords[firstLetter];
        }else{
            return;
        };

        for(let k=0; k<curArray.length; k++){

            if(curArray[k].indexOf(val)!==-1){
                variants.push(curArray[k]);
            };
        };

        if(!variants.length){
            variantsBlock.style.opacity = 0;
            return;
        } 

        varMod.clearVars(variantsBlock);

        for(let k=0; k<variants.length; k++){
            let itemSpan = document.createElement('span');
            itemSpan.textContent = variants[k];
            itemSpan.setAttribute('value', variants[k]);
            itemSpan.classList.add('varianItem');
            variantsBlock.appendChild(itemSpan);

            itemSpan.innerHTML = itemSpan.textContent.replace(
                    val, 
                    (m)=>{
                        return `<span style="color: orange">${m}</span>`;
                    }
                );
        };
    };
    /////////////////////////// (1) ///////////////////////////

    /////////////////////////// (2) ///////////////////////////
    function clearVariants(variantsBlock){
        while(variantsBlock.firstChild){
            variantsBlock.removeChild(variantsBlock.firstChild)
        };
    };
    /////////////////////////// (2) ///////////////////////////

    return {
        createSpan : createSpanItems,
        clearVars : clearVariants
    };

})();

document.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
    if(e.target.className === 'varianItem'){
        varMod.clearVars(variants);
        variants.style.opacity = 0;
        input.value = e.target.getAttribute('value');
    }
});


input.addEventListener('input', function(e){

    let val = input.value.toLowerCase(),
        firstLetter = val.slice(0,1).toLowerCase();

    if(!val){
        varMod.clearVars(variants);
        variants.style.opacity = 0;
    } 
    
    if(!wordsObject[firstLetter]) return;

    if(val){
        variants.style.opacity = 1;
        varMod.createSpan(input, variants, wordsObject);
    };

});
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    background: aliceblue;
}

.input-wrapper{
    display: block;
    position: relative; 
    margin: 240px auto;
    width: 300px;
    height: 36px;
}

.input, .variantsDiv{
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    border-radius: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 19px;
}

.input{
    display: block;
    padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    font-family: 'Arial'
}

.variantsDiv{
    min-height: 36px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 125%;
    left: 0px;
    border: 2px solid gray;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-Y: scroll;
}

.varianItem{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 36px;
    line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
}
.varianItem:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" class="input">
    <div class="variantsDiv">
    </div>
</div>
```

Делаю инпут с автозаполнением, мне нужно чтобы в инпуте работали стрелки вниз/вверх ( как вы уже догадались для выбора вариантов ), но не знаю как отменить стандартное действие браузера по умолчанию ! Подскажите пожалуйста, чот я даже отследить событие нажатия этих пнопок вверх / вниз не могу ! p.s.: пока в объекте на автозаполнение прописал только слова на три буквы " a , b , p ", чисто для тестов!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что добавил:

В CSS: Рядом с :hover, `.varianItem.active` — элементы с обоими классами получат те же стили.

```
input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (!/Arrow(Up|Down)/.test(e.key)) return; // Если не стрелки - прервать;

  e.preventDefault(); // Дошло сюда, значит стрелки. Блокировать поведение по умолчанию;
  
  let suggestions = document.querySelectorAll(".variantsDiv .varianItem");
  if (suggestions.length == 0) return; // Подходящих слова нет - прервать;
  
  let active = document.querySelector(".variantsDiv .varianItem.active");
  
  let curr_index = [].indexOf.call(suggestions, active);
  // Номер текущего активного слова среди всех предложенных

  let change_index = e.key.includes("Up") ? -1 : 1;
  // Стрелка вверх ? надо будет уменьшить индекс на 1 : вниз - увеличть.

  let new_index = (curr_index + change_index + suggestions.length) % suggestions.length;
  
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");
  suggestions[new_index].classList.add("active");
});
```

Здесь `curr_index` может получить значение -1, если класс active еще никуда не добавлен (null). В таком случае если тыкнули стрелку вверх, нужно превращать его в `= suggestions.length` чтобы выделился нижний элемент. Чтобы не уродовать код здесь, в цикле `for( k... variants)` добавил строчку `if (k == 0) itemSpan.classList.add('active');` — по умолчанию всегда первый элемент будет выделен.

```js
let input = document.querySelector('.input'),
  variants = document.querySelector('.variantsDiv'),
  wordsObject = {
    'a': ['amy', 'any', 'aky', 'ammy', 'aby', 'aty', 'azy', 'ally', 'aly'],
    'b': ['boy', 'boom', 'by', 'burn', 'build', 'back', 'background', 'boo'],
    'p': ['pick', 'pook']
  };


let varMod = (function() {

  /////////////////////////// (1) ///////////////////////////
  function createSpanItems(input, variantsBlock, objOfWords) {
    let val = input.value.toLowerCase(),
      firstLetter = val.slice(0, 1).toLowerCase(),
      curArray,
      variants = [];

    if (objOfWords[firstLetter]) {
      curArray = objOfWords[firstLetter];
    } else {
      return;
    };

    for (let k = 0; k < curArray.length; k++) {

      if (curArray[k].indexOf(val) !== -1) {
        variants.push(curArray[k]);
      };
    };

    if (!variants.length) {
      variantsBlock.style.opacity = 0;
      return;
    }

    varMod.clearVars(variantsBlock);

    for (let k = 0; k < variants.length; k++) {
      let itemSpan = document.createElement('span');
      itemSpan.textContent = variants[k];
      itemSpan.setAttribute('value', variants[k]);
      itemSpan.classList.add('varianItem');
      if (k == 0) itemSpan.classList.add('active');
      
      variantsBlock.appendChild(itemSpan);

      itemSpan.innerHTML = itemSpan.textContent.replace(
        val,
        (m) => {
          return `<span style="color: orange">${m}</span>`;
        }
      );
    };
  };
  /////////////////////////// (1) ///////////////////////////

  /////////////////////////// (2) ///////////////////////////
  function clearVariants(variantsBlock) {
    while (variantsBlock.firstChild) {
      variantsBlock.removeChild(variantsBlock.firstChild)
    };
  };
  /////////////////////////// (2) ///////////////////////////

  return {
    createSpan: createSpanItems,
    clearVars: clearVariants
  };

})();

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if (e.target.className === 'varianItem') {
    varMod.clearVars(variants);
    variants.style.opacity = 0;
    input.value = e.target.getAttribute('value');
  }
});

input.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (!/Arrow(Up|Down)/.test(e.key)) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  
  let suggestions = document.querySelectorAll(".variantsDiv .varianItem");
  if (suggestions.length == 0) return;
  
  let active = document.querySelector(".variantsDiv .varianItem.active");
  
  let curr_index = [].indexOf.call(suggestions, active);
  let change_index = e.key.includes("Up") ? -1 : 1;  
  let new_index = (curr_index + change_index + suggestions.length) % suggestions.length;
  
  if (active) active.classList.remove("active");
  suggestions[new_index].classList.add("active");
});

input.addEventListener('input', function(e) {

  let val = input.value.toLowerCase(),
    firstLetter = val.slice(0, 1).toLowerCase();

  if (!val) {
    varMod.clearVars(variants);
    variants.style.opacity = 0;
  }

  if (!wordsObject[firstLetter]) return;

  if (val) {
    variants.style.opacity = 1;
    varMod.createSpan(input, variants, wordsObject);
  };

});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: aliceblue;
}

.input-wrapper {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 40px auto;
  width: 300px;
  height: 36px;
}

.input,
.variantsDiv {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border-radius: 5px;
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 19px;
}

.input {
  display: block;
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Arial'
}

.variantsDiv {
  min-height: 36px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 125%;
  left: 0px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  max-height: 300px;
  overflow-Y: scroll;
}

.varianItem {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 36px;
  line-height: 36px;
  padding: 0px 12px 0px 12px;
}

.varianItem.active, .varianItem:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-wrapper">
  <input type="text" class="input">
  <div class="variantsDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Там еще придется возиться со скроллом. Быстрое решение: `suggestions[new_index].scrollIntoView();`

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView - нужно поизучать параметры, или более детально всё прописать, через scrollTop / getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: спасибо за ответ, хм, а почему не работает с " keypress " а только с " keydown " ? Странно. . .

Comment: @Muranx Ну методом тыка выяснилось, keypress срабатывает только на 'enter' и кнопках, которые что-то печатают.